# Why does my doc element jump to the side of the page when I move it a little?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to drag an element a little way on a mousedown event, so that it reveals a new item which will be drawn underneath. But when I try a move, it jumps to all the way to the right side of the window. How do I make it move to where I wanted? I have tried changing positions from 'relative' to 'absolute' , I have tried setting the new position to a fixed x and y, and relative to the mouse event; they all give the same result.

Something wrong with my basic understanding here. As background, I have been using `vue.js` quite a lot, to avoid getting too involved with dom manipulation myself (as I'm not too experienced!), and came across this problem in a vue project. Initially I thought it was a problem with Vue, but I've now shown it not to be.

```js
document.getElementById("red").addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown);
      function mouseDown(e) {

        const el = e.target;
        // const x = e.pageX;
        // const y = e.pageY;
     
        const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
        const x = rect.left + 20;
        const y = rect.top + 20;

        el.style.left = `${x}px`
        el.style.top = `${y}px`

        const newrect = el.getBoundingClientRect();

        document.getElementById("from").innerHTML = "drag from:      " + rect.left + ", " + rect.top;
        document.getElementById("to").innerHTML = "try to drag to: " + x + ", " + y;
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "dragged to:     " + + newrect.left + ", " + newrect.top;
      }
```

```css
.box {
    position:relative;
    margin: auto;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    }
.button {
    position:relative;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Drag Drop Test</title>
  </head>
   
  <body>
    <div id="app" align="center" class="box">
      <button id="red" class="button" >Red</button>
      <p id="from"></p>
      <p id="to"></p>
      <p id="result"></p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you log `rect` to the console, then you will see that the original values for `top` and `left` are not `0`, as you appear to have assumed here.

Comment: I don't understand  - I haven't assumed anything; the snippet (as well as the console log) clearly shows what 'rect' is, both before and after the move

Comment: _"clearly shows what 'rect' is, both before and after the move"_ - yes; and what _is_ it before? If you _wanted_ to move the element 20px down and to the right, then the `top` and `left` values that you are adding 20px to here, would have to be 0 initially. But they aren't.

Comment: The `top` and `left` _CSS properties_ of a relative positioned element, are relative to the element itself. The `top` and `left` you read via `getBoundingClientRect`, are relative to the top-left of the _viewport_. So you need to take that difference into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button is moving to the extreme right because in your code here:

```
const el = e.target; //el is the button with id "red you click on

const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect(); //this returns the size of the button and its current position relative to the viewport(not the parent element)

const x = rect.left + 20;
const y = rect.top + 20;

el.style.left = `${x}px`//moves the button by 20px via x co-ordinate.
el.style.top = `${y}px //moves the button by 20px via y co-oridnate.
```

since in your CSS you have made both button and box to be relative, as soon as you push the button 20px from left and top, and since you haven't considered the dimensions of the parent element of the button which is the box in this case, the button moves to the farthest right. If you want to keep the button inside the box, then you have to get the positions of the button relative to the parent element and not the whole viewport also the position of button should be absolute as you have made the postion of box to be relative.

This is my code to achieve what I presume you want, a draggable button inside the box only. Hope this helps.

```js
const button = document.getElementById("red");
const box = document.getElementById("app");

const boxWidth = box.offsetWidth+3;
const boxHeight = box.offsetHeight+3;//including border

const buttonWidth = button.offsetWidth;
const buttonHeight = button.offsetHeight;

let dragStartX, dragStartY; //drag start posiitions
let buttonX, buttonY;

let isDragging; //to check if currently dragging or not
let marginReached=false; //to check wether the button reaches the margin of the box or not

button.addEventListener("mousedown", handleMouseDown);
button.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
button.addEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);

//handles mousedown events
function handleMouseDown(e){
  const boxRect = box.getBoundingClientRect();
  const buttonRect = button.getBoundingClientRect();
  const LEFT = buttonRect.left - boxRect.left;
  const TOP = buttonRect.top - boxRect.top;
  isDragging = true;//set dragging to true
  dragStartX = e.clientX; //mouse pointer position on x axis
  dragStartY = e.clientY; //mouse pointer position on y axis
  buttonX = LEFT;//position of button on x axis
  buttonY = TOP;//position of button on y axis
}

//handles mouse move events
function handleMouseMove(e){
  const mouseX = e.clientX;//current mouse position on x axis
  const mouseY = e.clientY;// current mouse position on y axis
  
  const moveFromLeft = mouseX-dragStartX+buttonX;
  const moveFromTop = mouseY-dragStartY+buttonY;
  
  //checks wether the button reaches the margin of the box and prevents it from going any further
  if(moveFromLeft>=(boxWidth-buttonWidth) || 
    moveFromTop>=(boxHeight-buttonHeight)||
    moveFromLeft<=0||
    moveFromTop<=0
    ){
    marginReached = true
  }else{
    marginReached = false
  }
  
    if(isDragging && !marginReached){
    button.style.left = `${moveFromLeft}px`
    button.style.top = `${moveFromTop}px`
  }
}

//handles mouse up events
function handleMouseUp(e){
    isDragging = false; //set dragging to false on mouse button release
}
```

```css
.box {
    position:relative;
    margin: auto;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    }
.button {
    position:absolute;
    left:25%;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Drag Drop Test</title>
  </head>
   
  <body>
    <div id="app" align="center" class="box">
      <button id="red" class="button" >Red</button>
      <p id="from"></p>
      <p id="to"></p>
      <p id="result"></p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: or if you just want the button to move automatically to a definite position without dragging it, then you can remove the mouseMove handler function and move its code inside the mouse down handler function, with further tinkering in the code, you can achieve that as well

Comment: Thank you. I will mark your answer as correct. I don't need to keep the button 'in the box'; the box will be a Vuetify container to hold several items (not buttons!) together and they can be dragged anywhere. And I already have working code to deal with the drag, so I have combined your two handlers as suggested. I only put the mouseDown handler in my question because I coudl see that the button was moving too far even before the mouseMove was handled. I will add some simplified javascript as an extra answer,

Comment: BTW I had tried using the container position to solve the problem, but hadn't done it correctly somehow. I will now go and adjust my original Vue code.

Comment: glad your problem was solved. :)

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying @Mol nAK's answer for my specific requirement, I just need the following:

```
  const button = document.getElementById("red");
  button.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown);

  function mouseDown(e) {
    const parentRect = button.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    const buttonRect = button.getBoundingClientRect();

    const moveFromLeft = buttonRect.left - parentRect.left;
    const moveFromTop =  buttonRect.top - parentRect.top; 
  
    button.style.left = `${moveFromLeft}px`
    button.style.top = `${moveFromTop}px`
  }
```